# How to "select by location" certain points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, select-by-location

I have a small problem - how to select the points on the line but not select the points at the intersections of lines using "select by location"? Illustration below. I am using ArcGIS 10.0

[image]

Comment: Point on line needs a tolerance, unless points *exactly* match an existing vertex on the line they may not be selected. Select within a distance from the blue line and then unselect the ones on the red line if you don't need them (select by location:remove from current selection). I think that's what you're after.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to get the points you want with just select by location because all of those points are in common no matter which selection method you use. In order to isolate them, you'd have to extract the vertices you want or don't want, and then select your points based on their location relationship to those extracted vertices. As Michael's answer that just appeared suggests. Do note that solution requires an Advanced License, however.

Answer (score 3):

1. Buffer (without dissolving) all lines a (very) small distance.
2. [Spatially Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) your points to your buffers with a one-to-one join_operation with an intersect match_option.
3. In the resulting feature class, there will be an attribute Join_Count of how
   many buffers matched each point. Any point at an intersection would
   intersect two buffers, while points anywhere else along the line
   would only intersect one buffer. Using select by attributes, you can
   select those points which only intersected one buffer.

Comment: That's pretty much the same thing except more interactive and visual, internally Select By Location buffers by the tolerance and selects, it keeps them in memory so you don't see them... by breaking it down into 3 steps with outputs you can easily see where you're going right/wrong and rectify it. +1 from me for compartmentalizing.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I mostly posted it as an alternative to Features to Vertices, since that requires the Advanced license. You could also forgo tolerances and open up the 'are identical to' selection method if you did create points out of the start/end nodes, but that does assume your points are *on* your lines (and a vertex at that if I understand right, but the FtV would be).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit more complex, you will need to create two temporary 'unselect' feature classes. Use the tool [Feature Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) with the 'BOTH_ENDS' specified to create points where you don't want selection. Do this for the blue and the red lines then [merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000).

Use [Select by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) to select the points within a small tolerance from the blue lines (how far depends on your data) then using the selection option "Remove from the Currently Selected features in" select against the end points created earlier to remove them from the selection.

Select 1 (use a tolerance):

[image]

Select 2 (remove unwanted):

[image]

Comment: Green point are the one you're selecting, vert2point are the ones created with Feature Vertices to Points and merged, you can see them as black stars in the 2nd image. Consider Chris has an excellent answer without the need for advanced license.

Comment: The difference between VERT2POIN and GREEN POIN be?

Comment: I'm create Green Point use the tool Feature Vertices to Points with the 'BOTH_ENDS' specified to create :)
GREEN POIN and VERT2POIN is one!